# How can I remove a className from a component when entering another component in react

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-dom

I am building a portfolio in React in which I am using my fixed navigation bar all the time, but I have another component that is another page called projects, in it images appear and when clicking on them a modal appears that gives all the data of said project, but my problem is that the navigation bar is still there and does not disappear, how can I make the navigation bar disappear when I open the modal? Is there a way to remove the class and when I close the modal, the class will appear so that the navigation bar continues?[shows how the navigation bar appears when opening the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8UMq.png)

Comment: I am wondering whether you are trying to hide the top menu or just want to bring the overlay to the top of the menu? If you check the menu HTML in developer tools, most probably there is a Z-Index property set on your menu which is causing it to show above the overlay.

Comment: Yes, I want the menu to stop showing up when I open the modal, either by removing the "fixed-top" class from bootstrap or just giving an overlay to the modal so that the menu is behind it and doesn't interfere with its appearance. , but I can't find a solution to this problem

Comment: Do you have any bootstrap classes used on your modal? If not, try adding a zindex of 1040 to your overlay.

Comment: I already solved the positioning problem with the z-index property of css, but a question, how can I delete a class in react, manipulating the dom, I have seen that it can be done with the useRef hook but I see that it accesses the reference of where it is the same element within that component, and what I want to do is remove className from another component

Comment: I wanted to apply the z-index to your overlay component so it will have a higher z-index than the menu so the menu will go under the overlay. I believe currently the overlay z-index is either not set or less than the menu.

Comment: Yes, I already solved it with the z-index, thank you very much for your help

Comment: I will add my comment as an answer if it can help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap there are a few z-index properties we need to take care of if we deviate from bootstrap classes.

```
$zindex-dropdown:                   1000;
$zindex-sticky:                     1020;
$zindex-fixed:                      1030;
$zindex-modal-backdrop:             1040;
$zindex-offcanvas:                  1050;
$zindex-modal:                      1060;
$zindex-popover:                    1070;
$zindex-tooltip:                    1080;
```

In your case, you need to apply the `zindex-modal-backdrop` value 1040 on your overlay so it will show on top of the menu.

Comment: a question, i'm new to the community, is there a way to rate you or what's next after i've solved a question

Comment: @bryanmartinez Try to use the classnames library  https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames, I hope it will solve your problem.